# JS Button Numbering in an Alert

Tags: javascript

I created a few boxes in a 3x3 pattern. I want each pattern to be stored with a value from 1-9. I'm unsure of how exactly how to do this.

My current code is this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("Alert from box");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <style>
    .prac {
      height: 150px;
      width: 50px;
      color: white;
      background-color: grey;
      border: 2px solid red;
      margin: 20px;
   </style>
   <body>
      <h2>Select a Discount Box!</h2>
      <button class="prac" onclick="myFunction()">One</button>
      <button class="prac" onclick="myFunction()">Two</button>
      <button class="prac" onclick="myFunction()">Three</button>
      <br>
      <button class="prac" onclick="myFunction()">Four</button>
      <button class="prac" onclick="myFunction()">Five</button>
      <button class="prac" onclick="myFunction()">Six</button>
      <br>
      <button class="prac" onclick="myFunction()">Seven</button>
      <button class="prac" onclick="myFunction()">Eight</button>
      <button class="prac" onclick="myFunction()">Nine</button>


   </body>
</html>
```

It currently just returns the same alert for all of them. I want it to alert with the same message plus the number of buttons that was clicked.

Comment: one could imagine setting onclick to `myFunction(1)` and `myFunction(2)`, etc. ... up to `myFunction(9)` Good enough?

Comment: According to your code, you have not passed any number to the function that shows the alert nor have you included any number in the alert text. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass in the argument directly by writing `onclick="myfunction(1)"` or make use of some additional markup to assign the buttons some ids and write `onclick="myfunction(this.id)"`  I'll demonstrate the latter:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Select a Discount Box!</h2>

<button id="1" class="prac" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">One</button>
<button id="2" class="prac" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Two</button>
<button id="3" class="prac" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Three</button>
<br>
<button id="4" class="prac" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Four</button>
<button id="5" class="prac" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Five</button>
<button id="6" class="prac" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Six</button>
<br>
<button id="7" class="prac" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Seven</button>
<button id="8" class="prac" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Eight</button>
<button id="9" class="prac" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">Nine</button>


<script>
function myFunction(id) {
  alert("Alert from box " + id);
}
</script>

<style>
.prac {
height: 150px;
width: 50px;
color: white;
background-color: grey;
border: 2px solid red;
margin: 20px;

</style>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Edit:**  A second approach that refactors to be a bit more efficient.  Assigns the click handler programmatically and retrieves the id of the event target.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Select a Discount Box!</h2>

<button id="1" class="prac">One</button>
<button id="2" class="prac">Two</button>
<button id="3" class="prac">Three</button>
<br>
<button id="4" class="prac">Four</button>
<button id="5" class="prac">Five</button>
<button id="6" class="prac">Six</button>
<br>
<button id="7" class="prac">Seven</button>
<button id="8" class="prac">Eight</button>
<button id="9" class="prac">Nine</button>


<script>
for (let elem of document.getElementsByClassName('prac')) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
}

function myFunction(e) {
  alert("Alert from box " + e.target.id);
}
</script>

<style>
.prac {
height: 150px;
width: 50px;
color: white;
background-color: grey;
border: 2px solid red;
margin: 20px;

</style>
</body>
</html>
```